# Laravel 5 Form Submit to View

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I'm recoding my website and moving over to Laravel but for some reason I can't figure out how to have a search form that redirects you to a profile page.

```
<form class="navbar-form navbar-right search" role="search" action="/profile/" method="GET">
<div class="input-group">
<input type="text" class="form-control navbar-player-search" placeholder="Enter IGN here" autocomplete="off" required>
        <div class="input-group-btn">
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">
                <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></i>
            </button>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

I have a route already set up which works if I went to example.com/profile/Callahan

```
Route::get('/profile/{Profile}', 'PlayerController@getStats');
```

but I need the form to do that same thing.
Is it possible to do this with default laravel 5.4.3 or do I need something like https://laravelcollective.com/docs/5.3/html?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't understand exactly the information which the input contains, but I'll consider this:

The user will write in the input and click on search.
Then, in your controller, you'll get the profile name after the search and redirect to the profile. Is that the case?

If yes, you should do something like that:

**Routing**

```
Route::get('/profile/{Profile}', 'PlayerController@getStats');
Route::get('/search', 'PlayerController@searchForm');
Route::post('/search', 'PlayerController@search');
```

**Controller**

```
public function searchForm() {
    return view('search');
}

public function search(Request $request) {
    // get the input
    $inputText = ...;
    // logic to get the profile name
    $profileName = ...;
    return redirect('/profile/'.$profileName);
}
```

**View**

```
<form class="navbar-form navbar-right search" role="search" action="/search" method="POST">
<div class="input-group">
<input type="text" class="form-control navbar-player-search" placeholder="Enter IGN here" autocomplete="off" required>
        <div class="input-group-btn">
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">
                <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></i>
            </button>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

Once again, I don't know if it's what you really want, but if it's not, let me know to try help you again.

Comment: public function searchForm() {
    return view('search');
}
would that need to be a blade view?

Comment: I have the html search bar code in a navbar at the top, on the old site I'd just have it submit post data to the page and then check if post data was sent and redirect them there

Comment: there's no need to use blade. the file could be just .php and will work fine. Right, so these codes works for you?

Comment: Adding that returns a MethodNotAllowedHttpException :(

Comment: After the POST? Can you edit the question for paste the error or an print? There's another code in the method search too? I'll need to see a bit more to help you.

Comment: You forgot the action="/search" ! Works like a charm now, you should edit your post to include that. Thank you so much!